# A Latin Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Data, my head protects all
In foreign tongue, my mid's the fall
My end: an ancient god of sun
No ordinary musician

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> SHAKIRA?

Data, my head protects all

> SHA protects data (it’s a Secure Hash Algorithm).

In foreign tongue, my mid's the fall

> AKI means autumn in Japanese.

My end: an ancient god of sun

> The Egyptian sun god RA.

No ordinary musician

> The Latin musician Shakira.

Comment: That's the correct answer.